# Cloning list items Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images. When the program starts I want to clone the list and prepend it.
This is my code so far:

```
var children = $("#imageList").children().clone();

$("#imageList").prepend(children);
```

Why will this not clone the children in the list? When I test the program I only have the original list.

**Update:** Here is the image list:

```
<ul id = "imageList"> <!-- List of scrolling images -->
                <li id = "image1" class = "ImagesScroller">
                    <div>
                        <a href "www.url.com">Somethimes Click This</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src = "Image1" height = "200" width = "500" alt = "/" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id = "image2" class = "ImagesScroller">
                    <div>
                        <a href = "www.url.com">Always Click This</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src = "Image2" height = "200" width = "500" alt = "/" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id = "image3" class = "ImagesScroller"> 
                    <div>
                        <a href = "www.url.com">Don't Click This</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src = "Image3" height = "200" width = "500" alt = "/" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id = "image4" class = "ImagesScroller">
                    <div>
                        <a href = "www.url.com">Click This (On Tuesdays)</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src = "Image4" height = "200" width = "500" alt = "/" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

It isn't just a list of images. Each image has a link on top of it that goes with that image. The images will animate (using .animate()) to cycle through. I need to append and prepend images so that the "loop" that I am making will be endless.

Comment: What does the markup for #imageList look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your code is inside a jQuery "ready" handler:

```
$(function() {

  var children = $("#imageList").children().clone();

  $("#imageList").prepend(children);
});
```

If you run that code in a `<script>` block in the `<head>`, then there won't be any elements in the DOM yet, so the code won't do anything.

You could alternatively put a simple script block (just your code, as posted), placed **after** the list and the images etc.

Comment: I have it all in a ready handler (Sorry for the confusion, i didn't show that much of my code I had). The next two lines I show in my question follow the " $(document).ready(function() { " line

Comment: Ah.  Well, that code looks fine. Can you show some of the HTML then? *edit* oh I see you just added it :-)

Comment: The list I used is in the updated section. That is just about all the html I have. Most of the rest of my code is working with animate() but I don't think that is causing this issue. I can add it if needed

Comment: Actually the issue was a CSS issue (I have the items, but they were hidden) so I guess the code was correct in the first place

Comment: Well, all's well that ends well, @SsRide360 :-) One thing to be careful of is that your list entries have "id" values. You may want to make sure your code constructs fresh, unique "id" values for cloned elements before adding them back to the DOM. A DOM with duplicated "id" values is a sad, confused DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say what might be wrong.  If you want to pre-pend children of a list your code looks correct.  See my example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><img src="/some/image1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="/some/image2.jpg"  /></li>
    <li><img src="/some/image3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var children = $("#list").children().clone();
    $("#list").prepend(children);    
});
```